# Executable War File Does Start - only for my user id

Tags: java, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

I have an executable war Spring Boot war file, built from IntelliJ, that I have started like this on Linux for a number of previous versions:

```
java -jar app.war
```

However, when I try to run the war file in the latest app version, it just hangs for me - nothing is output.  Running `ps x` shows Sl+, that the app is in an interruptiable sleep, is multi-threaded, and is in the foreground process group.

Another user has no issues in running the exact same executable war file with the exact same commandline.  For me, I don't even get the initial app ascii art.

- The file permissions are identical to past versions
- The user/group ownership is the same
- The previous versions still work (which rules out to me any java setup/classpath/environment variable issues)

Any recommendations for next steps in debugging would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you **sure** that the app is not running? Is it possible that the app is running but that there is no log ouput being written to console or to whateverr file you are viewing? i.e. that the app only _seems_ to be hanging/not running?

Comment: Right, the app is running (i.e. I can see it show up in the list of processes from ps -aux).  A colleague showed me strace.  Running strace provided continuous log output, so it does appear that the app is running and something continues to happen.  The output from strace is very difficult to read through.  There's a lot of futex, fstat messages along with open calls to the war file.

Comment: I updated the post to be more clear that the app is running